# Javascript: get window.location everything but host?

Tags: javascript

i have like

http://www.mydomain.com/hello/you

with `top.location.host`, i can get `"http://www.mydomain.com"`

with `window.location.href` i can get `"http://www.mydomain.com/hello/you"`

is there a chance to get just `"/hello/you"` ???

Comment: What could this possibly have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Anurag: while you're editing you might as well get rid of the redundant `toString` call on `location.host`.

Comment: yikes @no, did I overwrite while you were changing?

Comment: Anurag, nope, I can't edit yet :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
location.pathname
```

`pathname` will *only* return the path. If you want the `querystring` and optionally `hash`, you would need to combine the `search` and `hash` properties as well. Consider this url:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/glory?key=value&world=cup#part/of/page

location.pathname => "/path/to/glory"
location.search   => "?key=value&world=cup"
location.hash     => "#part/of/page"
```

If you want the entire thing,

```
/path/to/glory?key=value&world=cup#part/of/page
```

then just concatenate all these:

```
location.pathname + location.search + location.hash
```

Always wanted to use `with` somewhere. This looks like the perfect opportunity :)

```
with(location) {
    pathname + search + hash;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `search` and `hash`.

Comment: @Matthew - the querystring or the hash wasn't listed in OP's question, so I can't assume that he will want it, but what I can do is elaborate on my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be excluding the protocol and host from the entire href using substring.

```
window.location.href.substring(
    (window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host).length
)
```

If your url is `http://google.com/test?whatever=1#hello` it will return `/test?whatever=1#hello`.